# Why is Margin Top not working for my nav bar

Tags: css, margin, nav

so I am trying to recreate a website and I am trying to make the nav bar centered horizontally and vertically, which I dont know how to do really so I have been just chaning the margin-top: (x amount of pixels); but for the middle part of my nav bar It is not changing and i dont know how to fix it.

the middle text is not changing no matter what i set .nav-bar margin-top too? any advice I am very new to coding so the simplier the better if possible
Html first then Css second

```
  <nav> 
      <ul >
        <li  >
             
        </li>
        <li  >
          <a  class="nav-bar-header" href="#">Medicare</a>
        </li>
        <li  >
          <a  class="nav-bar"  href="#">Individuals & Families</a>
        </li>
        <li >
            <a  class="nav-bar" href="#"> Businesses </a>
        <li >
          <a  class="nav-bar"  href="#"> Brokers </a>
        <li >
          <a  class="nav-bar" href="#">Providers  </a>
        <li >
            <a class="nav-bar-exit"  href="#">Shop Plans</a>
          <ul >
        </nav>



nav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: rgb(22, 123, 156);
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
   
    height: 4.5em;
    
       
}

.nav-bar-header {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #e7c9c9;
    float: left;
    font-size: 25px;
    
    
    padding-left: 30px;
    
    
}
.nav-bar {
  color: #e7c9c9;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 3em;
  margin-top: 2em;
  font-size: 15px;
  
  
}
ul { 
    margin-top: 16px;

}

.nav-bar-exit  {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #e7c9c9;
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 4px;
  
    font-size: 25px;
}
 
li {
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 30px;
     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `margin-top` will never work, because `a.nav-bar` is `inline` in nature and just does not have any space to grow and occupy. You have given `display: inline` to the `li`, as well, which will make the given `width` or `height` ineffective.
change the display to `inline-block` and give `height` and `width` to `li` and `.nav-bar`.

Also, you've given style classes to the `a` inside `li` but for alignment you need to give styles to the `li`. An element can only move inside the container according to space. Your main container here is the `ul`, so you'll have to apply styles to the `li` and move them accordingly in the container.

I can see an extra empty `li` in the beginning which you need to remove, I am sure if your styles work properly you'll not need it, and close the `ul` at the end, otherwise it will append another element in the dom.

Research a bit about `display: flex`, it will be less code and easier to manage the layout.